# Delete function in java script will delete the first index

Tags: javascript, crud

Scenario :

There are 5 div with delete button. I click the delete button of the div 5, instead the div 5 will be deleted the first of the row will b e deleted.

Please check my code below:

`delete row() function:`

```
function delete_row(no)
{
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
         document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
    } else 
     alert("Data is not deleted");
}
```

delete button is made

```
var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
            var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
            var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML=
            "<div class='myrow'><div id='row"+table_len+"'><img id='image_row"+table_len+"' src = "+new_image+"><div id='title_row"+table_len+"' class='titleData'>"+new_title+
            "</div><div class='descData' id='description_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_description+"</div><div><input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'><input type='button' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+",this)'></div></div></div>";

            document.getElementById("new_image").value="";
            document.getElementById("new_title").value="";
            document.getElementById("new_description").value="";
```

Comment: Please add the HTML....

Comment: the important thing that you need to show is **how is `delete_row` called**

Comment: Have you checked the value of no? Have you checked the id you deleted? You just post the question but without posting your tries.

Comment: Can you add the html?

Comment: I updated the code above

Comment: create a `fiddle` of your whole code which type of divs created ...!

Answer (score 0):

try this demo code and set your data like this

```js
function delete_row(no) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
    document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
  } else
    alert("Data is not deleted");
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1" onclick="delete_row(1)">
  1
</div>
<div id="row2" onclick="delete_row(2)">
  2
</div>
<div id="row3" onclick="delete_row(3)">
  3
</div>
<div id="row4" onclick="delete_row(4)">
  4
</div>
<div id="row5" onClick="delete_row(5)">
  5
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of deleting the correct `div`:

```js
var index = 1;

function add(){
  var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var new_image = "new_image"+index;
  var new_title = "new_title"+index;
  var new_description = "new_description"+index;
  index++;
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML =
      "<div class='myrow'><div id='row" + table_len + "'><img id='image_row" + table_len + "' src = " + new_image + "><div id='title_row" + table_len + "' class='titleData'>" + new_title +
      "</div><div class='descData' id='description_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_description + "</div><div><input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(this);'><input type='button' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ",this)'></div></div></div>";
}
function delete_row(target){
    console.log(target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove());
}
// add first item
add();
```

```html
<button id="add" onclick="add();">
add
</button>

<table id="data_table">

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code works for you.

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div>One <button class="btn">Delete</button></div>
    <div>Two <button class="btn">Delete</button></div>
    <div>Three <button class="btn">Delete</button></div>
    <div>Four <button class="btn">Delete</button></div>
    <div>Five <button class="btn">Delete</button></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript Code

```
document.querySelector('#main').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.remove());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kdtm9vLe/21/